# Aggregation procedure Worldwide Governance Indicators

Tags: aggregation, mle

understanding the methodology of the Worldwide Governance Indicators is tough (http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1682130). They estimate the true governance value by using an "unobserved component model".

1) If I am able to set up the MLE function to estimate the alphas, betas and sigmas, can I actually reproduce their estimates which they report in their weights-Spreadsheet (http://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/index.aspx#doc-sources)? Or is this not possible because they use individual indicators instead of the averaged source-data of the WGI?

2) They state that they suppress the time subscript in their notation to keep it simple. But if I want to calculate the MLE function, do I just put in the indicators for one year and repeat this procedure for all years? Or do I perform one mle with all indicators from all years?

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit:

I was now able to estimate the alphas, betas and sigmas of the representative indicators. Now I have to regress the non-representative indicators on the pre-estimate of governance (in an error in variables model):

Non-representative Indicator ~ pre-estimate governance

Therefore, I have to calculate the weighted pre-estimate governance (equation 2) and the standard errors (equation 3) (see paper above).

This is my r code for equation 2 and 3:

weights <- (SigmaMatrix)^(-2) / (1 + rowSums((SigmaMatrix)^(-2), na.rm=T))

gpre <- rowSums(rep(weights, each=nrow(x_nam))*((x_nam[,1:7]-AlphaMatrix)/BetaMatrix), na.rm=T)

sd <-  (1 + rowSums((SigmaMatrix)^-2, na.rm=T))^(-1/2)

For my eiv-regression I have to calculate the reliability which is -if I understand it correctly - according to the paper:

1-variance(u(j))/variance(gpre(j)) where "uj is simply the variance of the conditional mean of gj given in Equation (3), and since V[g*j] is observable"

My questions:

Did I correctly translate the equations in R?
How do I get the variance of u(j) and gpre(j), because the equations 2 and 3 give numbers for each country?

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to answer my questions:

1) It is actually possible to get the right estimate with their source data.
2) Just plug in the data for one year with all countries which have at least one observation.